# Wifi connection across different networks | returning from supended mode

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, suspend

I am using a HP laptop running ubuntu LTS, always upgraded and updated to the latest version.

I work in different places using WiFi connection. I can connect without problems to WiFi_1. Then I leave the laptop in suspended mode so that I can secure my work to continue in the next place. When I reach home or a cafe, 90% of the times the network manager is unable to find the WiFi signal, or any other wifi signal (including mobile hotspot). I have to restart the computer, and often times this works, the signal is encountered, but many other times restarting the system does not work at all and I spend the whole afternoon without internet connection.

I think this is related to some information from WiFi_1 that is remaining in the system (because I left it in suspended mode), that makes hard for any other connection to connect afterwards. How can we troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

make

```
/etc/systemd/system/net-resume.service
```

and write

```
[Unit]
Description=Restart networkmanager at resume
After=suspend.target
After=hibernate.target
After=hybrid-sleep.target
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/net-resume
[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

Next you check which driver you use (Tell me if you do not know where the name of the drive is written in the result of the command)

```
lspci
```

Then make

```
/bin/net-resume
```

and write

```
#!/bin/sh
modprobe -r [your kernel driver]
modprobe [your kernel driver]
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

And give the permission to execute

```
chmod +x /bin/net-resume
```

Finally you enable the service

```
systemctl enable net-resume.service
```